# generate a unique hex color from string

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I was wondering if there was any way to generate a random unique color based off a specified string. I've looked into JavaScript implementations but I need one in C#. The input string "1233A" should always return the same output hex color.

Comment: How does the JS implementation do it?

Comment: You *could* use `GetHashCode` of the string and treat that value as RGB, if you don't mind that different input strings could yield same color.

Comment: _generate a random unique color_ and _input string "1233A" should always return the same output_ don't go well together. If a string always yields the same color, its deterministic and not random

Comment: What you're asking is not possible. If you're using 24-bit color, you have 2^24 (about 16 million) possible colors. 2^32 if you're using 32-bit color. There is an essentially infinite number of strings, so you're guaranteed to have collisions (two strings that map to the same color). Do you have some restriction on the length of the strings?

Comment: That 1233A already looks like a hex number. Is that coincidence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an object's hash value to generate a color.

Here's a quick & dirty solution that produces RGBA values.

```
using System.Linq;

namespace System {
    static class StringExtensions {
        public static string ToHexColor(this string text) {
            if (text == null) text = string.Empty;

            int hash = text.GetHashCode();

            return $"#{hash:X8}";
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it with

```
string colorString = "My random string".ToHexColor();
```

Comment: Maybe add `Color myColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("My random string".ToHexColor());`. There's a catch: the Alpha may be so low that the resulting Color is actually invisible, if used. It could be remove or always set to `255` (implementation details).

Comment: Why the `BitConverter` and all that? Why not `hash.ToString("X8");`?